# Edit a comment in its association show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **Concert** model and **Comment** model

The user directly write his comments in the concert show, but for any reasons he may want to edit it...

What is the easiest way to do this? I don't want to go to the edit view, but I'd rather prefer to edit it in the show page...

How or can I use the same form that I have in that show?

I was thinking of a modal but I am not sure it's friendy user...

Any help would be very welcome

concerts/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @concert.kountry%> - <%= @concert.city %> - <%= @concert.venue %> </h1>

    <% @concert.comments.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.user.email %>
        <%= l(c.created_at, format: '%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S') %> - <%= link_to "Modifier", edit_concert_comment_path(c) %>
        <%= simple_format(c.content) %>
    <% end %>


    <%= simple_form_for([@concert, @comment]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :content, as: :text, placeholder: "your comment", label: false,  input_html: { rows: 3  } %>
        <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Best In Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem, hasn't been updated in a while but should still work.

#### modify form

```
<% @concert.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.user.email %>
  <%= l(comment.created_at, format: '%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S') %>
  <%= best_in_place(comment, :content, as: :textarea) %>
<% end %>
```

### then modify controller

```
def update
  @comment = Comment.find params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.update(update_comment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to(@comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.') }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@comment) }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@comment) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Antarr, it says undefined method `comment_path for #<#<Class:0x007fa799a19120>:0x007fa79a84fd48>
Did you mean?  concert_path` on this line ` <%= best_in_place(comment, :content, as: :textarea) %>`

Comment: What controller do you  currently use to update/create comment? What's the out put of running `rails routes` in the console?

Comment: I do this in the concerts controller